# Running C/C++ code in a webbrowser?

Tags: c++, flash, dll, browser, audio

I'm new to webdevelopment and I am looking for some tutorials or resources about how to run C++ code in a browser. I soon going to do a degree project which implements a sound service in a browser (like flash I guess) using a provided DLL + my own program, so I'm looking for some starters on where to look.

I don't have alot of webdevelopment experience but I do have a programming background C/C++.

Cheers

Comment: C++ code on the browser is usually only found in extensions (and ActiveX controls on Windows, which maybe were not such a good idea after all). Thus, the code you'll write will depend on the browser you target. Which one is it?

Comment: I know this changes the scope of your project, but you might want to check and see if you can open up the DLL via PHP or something.  I suppose there's always the old CGI (common gateway interface) route, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In almost all normal cases you would not want to have C++ code running in your web browser. Running C++ code is in most cases akin to giving full control of your computer to the running code. It can basically do anything, from installing viruses to deleting everything on your hard drive. This is something you would not want to allow any random website you visit to do.

With that being said, there are a few options to do this is a so called "secured" way. One way that only works on Microsoft Internet Explorer is using ActiveX controls. [Here's a page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751968%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) where you can start to learn about it.
Another option, that only works in google chrome at the moment is using Google's native client (NaCl). [Here's](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/) where you can start to learn about this option.
If you want to do it on firefox, you'll need the user to install an addin. [Here's](http://www.rietta.com/firefox/index.html) a good starting page for this option.

Normal web development uses Javascript instead of C++ to allow for programmability in web pages.

Comment: I agree with everything except Javascript is largely for the client side.  The server side uses PHP or ASP.NET, etc.

Comment: Javascript is not only client side, [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) is picking up popularity!

Answer (score 2):

[emscriptem](http://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki) will allow you to translate C/C++ into Javascript via LLVM.

According to that page

> Emscripten is an LLVM-to-JavaScript
>   compiler. It takes LLVM bitcode (which
>   can be generated from C/C++, using
>   llvm-gcc or clang, or any other
>   language that can be converted into
>   LLVM) and compiles that into
>   JavaScript, which can be run on the
>   web (or anywhere else JavaScript can
>   run).

Answer (score 0):

I think the browser should be used for HTML and JavaScript and that using C++ in a browser is not a good idea (just to have said it.)

If you want to run C/C++ code then you have to create a plugin. But plugins will be architecture/browser dependent and may not even be allowed on all platforms (iPhone/iPad). There are also secturity issues to deal with.

There are some toolkits for running C++ in a browser.

- For Windows you can use ActiveX controls and they can be written in C++ (ATL).
- Google has a [Native client](http://code.google.com/intl/no-NO/chrome/nativeclient/) for running C++ on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Using C++ in browsers is currently limited to browser plugins.

Microsoft Internet Explorer uses ActiveX and all the other browser vendors use NPAPI.

Googles Native Client is a sandbox that will need to eventually be a plugin in browsers other than Chrome.

I highly recommend that you take a look at the [firebreath](http://code.google.com/p/firebreath/) project for creating a plugin for both ActiveX and NPAPI.

There are not many cases for creating plugins other than visualizers for proprietary file formats or creating games that require accelerated graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly what you're trying to do, you may be able to get some use out of Adobe's Flash Alchemy - http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/ - which allows you to offload processing to pre-compiled C++ code. I think that's probably as close as you're going to get, though.