# Running a program using a webbrowser

Tags: c#, java, browser

I made a thread recently about running C/C++ programs in a webbrowser, and I got the response it would not work.

> [Running C/C++ code in a webbrowser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361968/running-c-c-code-in-a-webbrowser)

I've found out the framework I am to be using will have wrappers in other languages, so my question is, is it possible to run programs in a browser in the following languages:

-- C#, VB

-- Java

-- Python

-- Perl

-- Ruby

The framework in question is http://doubango.org/index.html, if it is any help.

Thanks

Comment: The question marked as "answered" in the original thread - using browser plugin tech such as ActiveX for IE - is the right answer IMHO.  The framework is native code - managed wrappers aren't going to change the level of security required to run it.

Comment: Even though there are wrappers in other languages, the framework is still in C, so you're back to square one, I'd think.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running C/C++ code in a webbrowser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361968/running-c-c-code-in-a-webbrowser)

Comment: that is my topic but it was about C/C++ code, I'm wondering about other languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The de facto language for running in the browser is JavaScript. The user has to *opt-out* if they don't want that to happen in their browser.

Anything else is going to need some sort of plugin support / ActiveX (in windows) control. (Including Flash. You could argue that *most* people will have flash installed, but it's still an opt-in.)

Comment: Can JavaScript in turn call any programs writen in another language?

Comment: JavaScript is normal programing language, so in theory you can write compiler from any language to JavaScript and run it that way. Or create PC emulator in JavaSctipt to run compiled code... But I don't think it will help you with your audio codec project :)

Comment: JavaScript can send messages to Java Applets running in the browser, for example.  The technology is quite mature and works on most (all?) major browsers. See Flanagan's JavaScript book for details.

Comment: @Theodore, Yes, *if the user has the java plugin installed*. In fact, you can interact with a number of user-installed plugins.

Answer (score 0):

All the languages you have listed allow you to create web applications. Here are some popular frameworks which could be used to create web sites using those languages:

- C#, VB.NET - [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/)
- Java - [Java Servlets](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Servlets.html)
- Python - [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/)
- Perl - [Gantry](http://www.usegantry.org/)
- Ruby - [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/)

Comment: Darin he's looking to write a client application bootstrapped in a browser.  Server-frameworks aren't going to work...

Comment: @stephbu, oh, if this is the case more details will be necessary about the scenario and what browsers need to be supported, etc... as it will be proprietary stuff anyway and require installing plugins on client computers.

Answer (score 0):

Goole Chrome provides a way to run native code inside the browser: http://code.google.com/chrome/nativeclient/